# How to debug in chrome for webpack+reactjs+babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I setup webpack-dev-server to serve as my development server. It packages all my source codes into one big javascript. It works fine but how I can debug my source code in chrome. I am able to open my js source code on chrome develop tool panel. But the breakpoints I added were not called during execution. Is there any plugin or extension I need to install?

Comment: try `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React developer tools is the best tool for debugging in the console.

Here is the link to the chrome extension and quick docs:

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/09/02/new-react-developer-tools.html